# Mover de lugar la pantalla

Tags: javascript, php

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy haciendo un chat con ajax y php, y lo que hago (sé que no es la mejor forma de hacerlo, entonces si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo agradecería si me dicen :) ) es hacer que cada 3 segundos ajax envía una petición a un archivo php para devolver todos los registros de una base de datos, lo cual lo hago de esta forma:

```
function ajax()
{
$.ajax({
    url: '<?=BASE_URL?>new/message',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data)
    {
    $('.message__area').html(data) //el message__area es solo un div
    }
})
}

setInterval(function(){ajax()}, 3000)
```

Y la forma en la que recibo los datos con php es así:

```
        $chat = new Chat(); //objeto de chat
        $all = $chat->all(); //metodo que devuelve todo los resultados
        while($message = $all->fetch_object())
        {
            //Aqui solo comparo para ver si el usuario fue el que envio o el que recibe el mensaje
            if($message->from_to === $_SESSION['user']->nickname)
            {
                echo <<<_END
                    <span class="message__received">$message->content</span>
                _END;
            }
            else
            {
                echo <<<_END
                <span class="message__send">$message->content</span>
            _END;
            }
        }
```

Hasta ahí todo bien ya que si funciona, pero lo malo es que cuando envió un mensaje la pantalla la deja donde esta, y a mi me gustaría que cuando se reciba un nuevo mensaje la pantalla se baje hasta el nuevo mensaje, no sé como hacerlo ya que soy muy, muy nuevo en javascript y no encontré mucha información en internet sobre esto, espero haberme explicado bien. Desde ya gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery tiene el método [.scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) que te permite desplazar el contenido y solo necesitas proporcionar como parámetro el [desplazamiento máximo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight). El `$('#chat')[0]` hace referencia al elemento HTML en vez de su instancia de jQuery:

```js
$('#send').on('click', e => {
    // Obtener mensaje sin espacios en los extremos
    let msg = $('#message').val().trim();
    // Solo si el mensaje no está vacío
    if(msg != '') {
        // Agregar mensaje al contenedor
        $('#chat').append(`<p>${msg}</p>`);
        // Ir hasta abajo
        $('#chat').scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);
        // Limpiar input
        $('#message').val('');
    }
});
```

```css
#chat {
    height:100px;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px #888 solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chat">
    <p>Comienza a enviar mensajes para probar.</p>
</div>
<input type="text" id="message">
<button id="send">Enviar</send>
```

Es muy mala idea hacer un chat con AJAX y, peor aún, cuando en cada petición lees todos los mensajes; al menos, deberías leer solo los últimos, filtrando por la fecha y hora posterior al último mensaje obtenido.

Comment: Triby muchas gracias, como dijiste ya funcionó, solo que cuando me regresa el último no alcanza a ver todo el texto, pero eso me imagino que es por los estilos que tengo

Comment: Otra cosa, se que esto no viene al tema pero de que otra forma me recomiendas hacer un chat? para tal vez hacerlo mejor

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía, efectivamente, debe ser por los estilos. Te recomiendo buscar información de Websockets. No estoy seguro, pero probablemente también [Server sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) podría servir.

Comment: bueno entonces arreglaré los estilos, y entonces voy a buscar de Websockets, muchas gracias :)